# Nodejs Mysql query throw err

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I try to register my user into a mysql database but an error appears 
I checked my database and the user is added but the error is still here.

**The Error :**

```
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
```

**My code :**

```
create : function(body, callback)
{
    var bind = [];

    for(prop in body) {
        bind.push(body[prop]);
    }

    let sql = `INSERT INTO users(email, firstname, lastname, password, language, currency, seed) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`;

    pool.query(sql, bind, function(err, lastId) {
        if(err) throw err
        callback(lastId);
    });
}
```

**pool.js**

```
const util = require('util');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: '**',
    user: '**',
    password: '**',
    database: '***'
});

pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if(err)
    {
        console.error("Something went wrong connecting to the database.");
    }

    if(connection) {
        connection.release();
    }
    return;
});

pool.query = util.promisify(pool.query);
module.exports = pool;
```

Comment: As you are using promisify may it don't needed pass the call back. Try to use `poll.query(sql, bind).then(...).catch(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a few solutions you can try here.

- In your `pool.js` file, just export `pool.query` and not the promisified version
- Surround your call to `pool.query` in the `create()` function with a promise and resolve the promise with the `lastId` variable instead of using a callback
- Use npm `mysql2` as it comes with a promise wrapper: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper

Hope that helps!